# How to fix this error `conflicting_dependencies'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got this error when tried to do rails s

```
rvm/rubies/ruby2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/resolver/conflict.rb:47:in `conflicting_dependencies': undefined method `request' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

What does it mean?

This is my gemfile

```
ruby '2.4.0'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'pg', '>= 0.18', '< 2.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
gem 'devise', '~> 4.5'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.2', '>= 5.2.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.1'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem 'paperclip-cloudinary'
gem 'paperclip-av-transcoder'
gem "paperclip-ffmpeg", "~> 1.2.0"
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.3'
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 10.0', '>= 10.0.1'
gem 'nprogress-rails'
gem 'notifications', '~> 0.6.0'
gem 'rest-client', '~> 2.0', '>= 2.0.2'
```

Something wrong with my gem version? i haven't opened it in a long time.

Comment: Please add some more information about your environment. This smells a bit like https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2665, which got closed after failed reproduction. Could be a similar mysterious issue.

Comment: what information u need?

Comment: i cant type rails -v in my terminal, maybe something wrong with my rails version?